Построение графика рациональной функции
помогите, пожалуйста, построить график
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 400)
f_x = (x + 2)2 / (x2 + 4)
    
plt.axhline(y=1, color='r', linestyle='--', label='y = 1 (асимптота)')
plt.plot(x, f_x, label='f(x) = (x + 2)^2 / (x^2 + 4)', color='b')
plt.title('График функции')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(-1, 5)
plt.show()


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

надо описывать суть вопроса, все-таки.

Возведение в степень в Питоне делается с помощью оператора **. Кроме этого я только подключил библиотеки, расставил переносы строк и сохранил график в файл. Так то я ваш код по сути не менял, он рабочий в остальном.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 400) 
f_x = (x + 2)**2 / (x**2 + 4)

plt.axhline(y=1, color='r', linestyle='--', label='y = 1 (асимптота)') 
plt.plot(x, f_x, label='f(x) = (x + 2)^2 / (x^2 + 4)', color='b') 
plt.title('График функции') 
plt.xlabel('x') 
plt.ylabel('f(x)') 
plt.grid() 
plt.legend() 
plt.ylim(-1, 5) 
plt.savefig('graph_x2.png')
plt.show() 


